# Must I develop my bishop on next move?

Tags: opening

I got to this position, while playing this game: https://lichess.org/dT3d9Dp4

Here I feel the need to develop my bishop. I thought of Bf4 but I feared g5, after  which I will lose a tempo. Be3 always make me think of a pawn fork on d4 or e4. I feel Bd2 is too passive. What frustrates me most is that developing the bishop might not even be necessary at this position. How will I know what to do? Is developing the bishop necessary?

```
[FEN ""]
[Startply "12"]

1.e4 Nc6 2.d4 e6 3.Nf3 h6 4.Bd3 d5 5.O-O Nge7 6.Nc3 a6
```

Comment: You blocked both your c- and f- pawn even though black didn't force you to, now it can take a while before you have a relevant pawn break.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't mean "3.Nf3" in the game snippet you provided? I looked at the game link and edited this post in accordance with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you are ahead in development, it will benefit you to open the center, or prepare for that, so Rook to e1 seems to be good altenative, 
it will benefit you to:

1- have a plan
2- develop based on that plan,

so, here I would play Re1 and wait to see where balck is going to castle, and then go after his knig, or open the  center if it remains there,

---

PS: another suggestion would be to play e.d5 immediately, the idea behind it is to try to open up the game ASAP and not let black develop harmoniosuly

Answer (score 2):

You don't *have* to develop your Bishop on the next move. `Bf4` does look ok, however. `Re1` also looks good as it will support the `e` pawn.

Comment: Re1 was my first thought as well - not only supports the e pawn but with a K on e8 a few moves away from castling pressure down the e file can be no bad thing. It also delays the decision on what to do with the Bishop, as well as the squares suggested a3 is not an impossible especially if the e file opens

Comment: The squares suggested a3?

Answer (score 1):

You *should* develop your bishop at some early point in the game, because your aim is to assign every piece the best responsibility as possible. But you don't have to do it now.

You don't have to be afraid of g5 because it would weaken your enemy's kingside (for example, it wouldn't be safe for him to castle on that side). Besides, you are ahead in development.

Bd2 is also a good development option for the bishop. Developing doesn't imply an active move or attacking.

Comment: I think Bd2 isn't good, because then black wins a pawn with ...dxe4 and ...Nxd4. The trick 1...dxe4 2.Nxe4 Nxd4 3.Nxd4 Qxd4 4.Bb5+! axb5 5.Qxd4 doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich is right, but I was trying to address the mentioned passiveness of a development move, in general.

Comment: And I am stressing the importance of concrete lines over terms like "passiveness" :-). That it blocks the defense of d4 could be considered a sign of passivity, or maybe you disagree, but a pawn is a pawn.

Answer (score 1):

The old rule about knights before bishops was because it's not always clear where the bishop should go right away.  In this position, you've already castled while it will take black two more moves to get to that point.  Accordingly, I would  get your rook to e1 first before developing the bishop, open up the center with exd5 while the black king still remains there and develop a strong attack against it.  Then your queen bishop could play a more active role, perhaps at f4.  As someone has mentioned, black's playing ..., g5 would weaken his kingside, so shouldn't be of great concern. Alternately you could play a French Advance type of move with e5 here to gain space in the center and then continue developing, since black has blocked his "c" pawn with the queen knight and can't attack the base of your pawn chain with ..., c5 immediately. Your queen bishop could potentially be of use then on e3 to add support to your d4 pawn if needed.

Comment: But White has already castled...

Comment: Right, I didn't notice that in the diagram. That's even better for white, since he can bring his rook to e1 right away and then open up the "e" file to begin action against the black king.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I felt ...g5 was to my disadvantage because black could still castle long and he'll have heads up in pawn push attack

Comment: It's going to take him at least 3 moves to castle long, and you're not going to be sleeping in the meantime.  You can launch an attack against his queenside if you see that that's his intent.  That's how opposite side castling works, i.e. who gets there first with the most.   The "g" pawn isn't going to kill you all by itself.  It would need  help, which black is far from mobilizing yet.  You're white and have the initiative of the first move.  In addition, you're way ahead in development and have a strong center presence.  Under those circumstances you have an obligation to attack.  .

Comment: If you dilly dally, you just turn the initiative and attacking chances over to black.

Comment: And if you're really worried about that ..., g5 move after you play Bf4, you can always play h3 first to prevent the pawn's further advance as well as to provide a hiding place for the B.

Comment: I didn't realize this was a computer game until I just looked it up now.  Against the computer I usually play e5 in this type of position to close it since the computer is so strong at tactics but not as good at strategy.  Opening up the game with exd5 would give the computer more tactical chances.  I often play the lichess computer at this level and get much better results with this approach.  Against a human though you can be more aggressive since they're not going to be as tactically perfect as the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't develop just to develop.  You need a plan, and you need to understand the position.
First, your d-pawn is under assault and there is a reason for the saying "Knights before Bishops; so why not consider Nf3?

Black has played a lot of pawn moves and the Ne7 blocks his development.  Where is he going to go next?  I would look to castle and play Re1 -- the Bishop on c1 doesn't know what it wants to do yet.

Comment: I think OP might have mistyped with "3.Nf6" in the provided game snippet instead of "3.Nf3". This seems to have messed up the game viewer causing an incorrect position to appear for you.

Answer (score 0):

Just always have a plan and take initiative. Study opening,middlegame and endgame phases. White is doing just fine on the position. Black is playing passive. Rook or bishop development is good.